Best way to bend an elastic line without it snapping
I am a biochemist and I need to bend a polymer-coated silica line
https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/capillary-tubing
the line is elastic but it is prone to snapping under tension. Hence I need to minimise tension at the bend. Could someone please tell me what is the best way to minimise tension at the bend: should the parts of the line be paralel before and after the bend or should I cross them.
Somehow it feels that crossing them minimises tension, but I am not a physicist and I dont have a justification for this. If you have a reference this would also be appreciated


If your curve is inextensible, a simple model would be elastica theory or for small deflections Euler-Bernoulli beam theory (does not seem like the case in your example). What are the constraints? Are you imposing the position of the ends and forcing a U turn ?

no I just grab the ends and move them closer together until I get the size of the bend that I need. TBH I dont need an ultra precise answer here. I just need to know approximately what to do

Large radius bends? When you bend a fiber, the inside is compressed and the outside stretched. Minimize the stretching by keeping the radius large.

This is an interesting topic, but I question whether the diagram marked "parallel" is possible by holding only the ends. As mentioned above, the shape is expected to be that of the elastica (see Fig. 8). "Grab the ends" is little too ambiguous; it's not clear whether you're allowing the ends to freely rotate or not as you manipulate them. Can you clarify? Photos of the deformation would help.
